# pygame transparent window alpha?

Tags: pygame, window, transparent, win32gui, layered

I was trying to make a pygame window background transparent, I did it with this code:

```
import win32gui, win32con, win32api
import pygame

pygame.init()
w,h = 400,200
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))

#font
pygame.font.init()
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial",128)

# Create layered window
hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,
win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED)

# Set window transparency color
transp = (255, 0, 128)  # Transparency color
win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(*transp), 0, win32con.LWA_COLORKEY)

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    #Drawing text
    screen.fill(transp)
    text = font1.render("hello",True,(255,255,255))
    screen.blit(text, (40,40))

    pygame.display.update()
```

It works fine until I try to draw images with antialiasing;
this is what happens:
[image]

The pixels with transparent alpha value become fuchsia :(
I've seen that this can be fixed using **win32gui.UpdateLayeredWindow()** but I didn't find any way to do it in a pygame window. If someone can help me I would be really grateful.

Comment: I am relatively sure that this is not possible. You specify one color key, which each pixel either is or is not. There is not scalable alpha there.

Comment: What would you like to see in place of that fuchsia pixels?

Comment: I would like to see the white semi transparent pixels of the image

Comment: For this to work you have to use `win32con.LWA_ALPHA` instead of `win32con.LWA_COLORKEY`. However, I have no idea how to change the display _Surface_'s alpha channel or whether this is even possible.

Comment: after set the window's WS_EX_LAYERED on, donot call SetLayeredWindowAttributes (this will make you window has only one color transparent, so it will be aliased), use UpdateLayeredWindow instead, you need prepare a memory DC and a 32-bpp bitmap. update the bitmap pixel data (donot use GDI functions, because they will clear alpha channel unconditionedly) to update your window. in this case, you also canot add any common controls on window (because system wonot draw common control for a per-pixel alpha blended window), if you want a control, you must draw it by youself (like DirectUI does).

Answer (score 1):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784745/pygame-transparent-window-alpha/74419818#comment122193889_68784745) posted by [Exlife](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10651270) (with copy edits):

> Do not call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` after enabling `WS_EX_LAYERED` for the window (this will only make the window monochrome transparent so it will be aliased), use `UpdateLayeredWindow` instead. You need to prepare a memory DC and a 32-bpp bitmap. Update the pixel data of the bitmap (don't use GDI functions, because they delete the alpha channel unconditionally) to update your window. In this case, you also can't add ordinary controls to the window (because the system doesn't draw ordinary controls for a window with alpha blend per pixel), if you want a control, you have to draw it yourself (like DirectUI).